# How to create a new object with Ajax request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

For example I have my index view with all objects in database. And instead of clicking on Create button I want to get it done without refreshing the page using Ajax. How to do it? How can I change my controller for this purpose? Thanks in advance.

**My controller**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authorize, only: [:edit, :new, :destroy]

  def index
    @articles = current_user.articles
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end


  def create
    @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to user_articles_path(current_user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
    if @article.update(article_params)
      format.html {redirect_to user_articles_path(current_user), notice: 'Post was successfully updated'}
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html {render action: 'edit' }
    end
  end
 end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    respond_to {|format| format.js }
  end

  private

    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title)
    end
 end
```

Comment: Please include your controller code.

Comment: You need to call (with ajax) the same url, method and params as the normal form request would do.  Then, in your controller, have a format.js block which specifies what javascript should be run in the success callback of the ajax call.

Comment: Please read ALL of this before asking any more questions.  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @MaxWilliams Can you provide some little example in the answer, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ***Ajax***, you need a ***form/link/button*** with `remote:true` option, a ***controller action*** to handle the `JS` request and a corresponding view page.

```
#new.html.erb
<%= form_for @article, remote: true do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<b>List of Articles</b>

<ul id="articles">
<%= render @articles %>
</ul>
```

As you want it for creating the articles, change your `new` and `create` methods like below

```
#articles_acontroller
def mew
@article = Article.new
@articles = current_user.articles
end

def create
@article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

  if @article.save
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to user_articles_path(current_user) }
    format.js 
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 end
end
```

Add a `create.js.erb` file

```
#create.js.erb
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @article) %>").appendTo("#articles");
```

And a `_article.html.erb` to display the created articles.

```
<li><%= article.title %></li>
```